# Zipf's Law explanation

Tags: statistics, nlp, text-mining, tm

I'm new to NLP and text mining and just heard about Zipf's Law. I've somewhat understood its explanation through [the Wikipedia page on the topic](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law).

Can anyone explain to me with a simple graph/example/code what is happening.

Comment: This sounds like a statistical question not a programming one. Furthermore the `R` tag... why?

Comment: Zipf's law is an empirical observation, there is no fundamental explanation for this. It can be considered as one example of a typical property of complex systems (in this case language), where 1/f^alpha statistics (or scaling) is frequently observed. You may want to take a look at the excellent book by [Per Bak](https://books.google.com/books/about/How_Nature_Works.html?id=x8nSBwAAQBAJ) for a popular introduction into complex systems. Among many other phenomena, it also discusses to a good extent Zipf's Law.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a definition in the context of information retrieval and a nice graph in the [IR book](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/zipfs-law-modeling-the-distribution-of-terms-1.html).